# how to make R datafile to Python type

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rpy2

I want to make R datatype to Python datatype below is the whole code

```
def convert_datafiles(datasets_folder):
import rpy2.robjects
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
pandas2ri.activate()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(datasets_folder):
    for name in files:
        # sort out .RData files
        if name.endswith('.RData'):
            name_ = os.path.splitext(name)[0]
            name_path = os.path.join(datasets_folder, name_)
            # creat sub-directory
            if not os.path.exists(name_path):
                os.makedirs(name_path)
            file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            robj = robjects.r.load(file_path)
            # check out subfiles in the data frame
            for var in robj:

                ###### error   happend right here
                myRData = pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe( var  )
                ####error happend right here



                # convert to DataFrame
                if not isinstance(myRData, pd.DataFrame):
                    myRData = pd.DataFrame(myRData)
                var_path = os.path.join(datasets_folder,name_,var+'.csv')
                myRData.to_csv(var_path)
            os.remove(os.path.join(datasets_folder, name)) # clean up

print ("=> Success!")
```

I want to make R datatype to pythone type, but the error keeps popping up like this : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dtype'

How should I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The [rpy2 documentation](https://rpy2.github.io/) is somewhat incomplete when it comes to interaction with pandas, but unit tests will provide [examples of conversion](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/src/5eba8cb3777c14f96c14ec4ebd8fc38323fe9da8/rpy/robjects/tests/testPandasConversions.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#testPandasConversions.py-168). For example:

```
rdataf = robjects.r('data.frame(a=1:2, '
                    '           b=I(c("a", "b")), '
                    '           c=c("a", "b"))')
with localconverter(default_converter + rpyp.converter) as cv:
    pandas_df = robjects.conversion.ri2py(rdataf)
```